# I need to find the mean for the data with cells without values

Tags: r, mean, factors

I need to find the average prices for all the different weeks. I need to make a ggplot to show how the price is during the year.
When you find the mean how does the empty cells affect the mean?

I have tried several thing including using the melt() function so I only have 3 variables. The variable are factors which I want to find the mean of.

```
Company variable value
ns  Price week 24   1749
ns  Price week 24    
ns  Price week 24   1599
ns  Price week 24    
ns  Price week 24    
ns  Price week 24   359
ns  Price week 24   460
```

I got more than 300K obs, and would love to have a small data.frame where I only have the Company, Price of different weeks as a mean. Now I have all observations for each week and I need to use the mean for using GGplot.

When I use following code

```
dat %in% mutate(means=mean(value), na.rm=TRUE)
```

I got a warning message saying the argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA.

I am looking forward to getting your help!

Comment: Hi, welcome. Could you explicit what are tour 3 variables? I understand that 'Company' = "ns Price week", 'variable' = 24, and 'value' = 1749 (for the first row). Is it correct? 
Also, applying mean on a column/vector with empty cells should ignore the empty cells.

Comment: I think you're getting the error because you're giving the `na.rm = TRUE` argument to the mutate function, instead of the `mean`: try replacing your last line of code with `mutate(means=mean(value, na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: Hi, thank you.The variables is explained further here: Company is of course which company it is, where the price week is the price for the given week for a given house. Fx. the price for the first house for company ns in week 24 is 1749. The value is therefore the price. I have tried to change the last line of code but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

**Clean code from PavoDive's comment**

```r
dt[!is.na(value), mean(value), by = .(price, week)]
```

and even better

```r
dt[ , mean(value, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(price, week)]
```

**Original:**
This works using `data.table`. The first part filters out rows that don't have a number in value. Next is to say we want the average from the value column. Final the by defines how to group the rows.

**Code:**

```r
dt[value >0 | value<1, .(MeanValues = mean(`value`)), by = c("Price", "Week")][]
```

**Input:**

```r
dt <- data.table(`Price` = c("A","B","B","A","A","B","B","A"),
                  `Week`= c(1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2),
                  `value` = c(3,7,2,NA,1,46,1,NA))

   Price Week value
1:     A    1     3
2:     B    2     7
3:     B    1     2
4:     A    1    NA
5:     A    2     1
6:     B    2    46
7:     B    1     1
8:     A    2    NA
```

**Output:**

```r
1:     A    1        3.0
2:     B    2       26.5
3:     B    1        1.5
4:     A    2        1.0
```

Comment: `dt[!is.na(value), mean(value), by = .(price, week)]` and even better `dt[ , mean(value, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(price, week)] ` would be less idiomatic. You can get rid of all those single and double quotes. Also: you don't need the final `[]`, as the result will print automatically (it's needed when you make an assignment with `:=`)

Comment: Thank you PavoDive. I could not think of those na commands before. That's a great clean up. The [] was intentional so it would print but I could see how that could be unclear to jack.

Comment: No worries! I commend you for coming here and helping others (and learning in the process). Good job!

Comment: Hi PavoDive and Korinda. Thanks for the answers, but I am still having trouble getting it to work. Do I need to use a data.table for this to work or does my columns need to be any thing specific? Company and variable are both factors where value is chr

Comment: wd<-wdat1 %>% group_by(variable, Company) %>% summarise_all(Avereage =mean(value), na.rm=TRUE) If I use that code I will get every week for the first company (ns) but I got no value outside of every week. It just say NA.. The warning is: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA.. Do any of you know why and why does the other companies not appear? I would like every company with the average price for each week.. After that I need to plot it

Comment: I got it to work through following code: a<-aggregate(wdat1, by=list(Company = wdat1$Company, variable= wdat1$variable), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)

Comment: @jackpetersen I'm glad you found something that works for you; and yes the solution @PavoDive and I provided does require the `data.table` library to be loaded. With 300k+ observations it's worth looking into for a performance boost (if/when that becomes a problem).

Comment: Thanks Korinda! I got a new problem you might be able to help me with? I am looking to plot the Occupancy rate for the weeks for each company. My problem is that the Occupancy rate I have in the data is for the enitre period and don't tell us anything about each week. So first I have to find the Occupancy rate for each company for every week and I have come up with this code; sum(D1$Company=='dc' & D1$`Price week 24`== " ") / sum(D1$Company=='dc' & D1$`Price week 24`!=-10). It works but I am wondering if I can do it faster so we a new coloum with the result for each company?

Comment: @jackpetersen I've been mulling over your question but I'm having a hard time understanding what you are asking. The dataset you provided in your original question does not include Occupancy nor empty price weeks nor negative price weeks.

Comment: The dataset I uploaded was a edited one where the occupancy was remove because it wasn't relevant for that question. The new question if is I can make a formula where I get a new column to my dataset which contain the occupancy rate for each company. At this moment I have the code above which works, but then I have to make it for every company, and was wondering if I could write it another way. The way I would prefer would return a column with the occupancy rate for each company at a given week.